# how to convert matlab Long line equation to c++?

Tags: c++, matlab, long-integer, equation

I converted some matlab code to c++. Some lines of the code have about 250,000 length. In addition, they involve very big mantissa numbers such as “2.209647215146515615616515615615103202897891
316e-258” and the precision is important to me (I know the number is very near to zero, but I can’t replace it with zero).

These codes run in matlab perfectly (fast and exact), but in c++, there is some problem:

- First: the build time takes too long.
- Second: after spend a long time for build, it works very very very slow!
  I’m Using Visual Studio 2015 and when write this codes in it, it stopped working because of the huge size of lines and preprocessing tasks and I have to restart it.
  Is there any way to work with long lines of code and very big numbers in c++ and Visual Studio IDE?

Comment: Please try to localise your problem and supply an [mcve]. Can't you simplify your expressions?

Comment: Have you tried `unsigned long long`?

Comment: @pandoragami That will not work since unsigned long long is first of all only for integers and this question is using doubles. Next, unsigned long long can only hold numbers around 20 digits, while this requires numbers that are around 250 digits in percision.

Comment: @Arnav, point taken.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try GMP from gmplib.org

> GMP is a free library for arbitrary precision arithmetic, operating on
>   signed integers, rational numbers, and floating-point numbers. There
>   is no practical limit to the precision except the ones implied by the
>   available memory in the machine GMP runs on. GMP has a rich set of
>   functions, and the functions have a regular interface.

You're question is very broad though plus since you're using Visual Studio it might be a nightmare to compile this with your existing library. I suggest you go over to Linux and work on that for "scientific computation".